# MySQL replace zeros with value from previous row

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, substitution

I have a column of values where the rows with 0 must to be substituted with value from a fixed row before the row with the zeros. Sample columns are below:

```
from |  to
------------
11   |  11
2    |  2
32   |  32
41   |  41
5    |  5
0    |  5
0    |  5
0    |  5
0    |  5
61   |  61
0    |  61
17   |  17
0    |  17
0    |  17
8    |  8
4    |  4
```

How can I achieve this? Would this require a recursive cte?

Comment: could you post the expected output as well?

Comment: Is there a column, like an id, that defines the order of the rows?

Comment: You'll need to share some additional information such as the table's clustered key or some column that defines the row order.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a column, like an `id`, which defines the order of the rows then you can use `MAX()` window function to locate for each row with `from = 0` the previous row with `from <> 0`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN `from` <> 0 THEN id END) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_id
  FROM tablename
)
UPDATE tablename t1
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN tablename t2 ON t2.id = c.prev_id
SET t1.`from` = t2.`from`
WHERE t1.`from` = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d81b6460b3d4e15c58fbaa352bb5f95a).